# android onTouchEvent. Different behaviour on different android versions

Tags: android, touch-event

I have simple activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("Event: ", event.getAction() + "");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

When I tab on screen (just put finger on the screen without any moving) onTouchEvent is called but has different result on android v4(4.2.2 or 4.4.2) and v5 (5.1).

**on Android 5.1**:
Event: 0 // this means ACTION_DOWN

**on Android 4 (4.2.2/4.4.2)**:
Event: 0 
Event: 2 
Event: 2 
Event: 2 
... 
Event: 2 
Event: 2 
...

so ACTION_DOWN and a lot of ACTION_MOVE.

I don't really understand why it happens. should I override some additional methods?

**UPDATED**

1. Android 4.2.2 (**Samsung Galaxy Tab 3**)
   Tab on screen. Result:
   .0. (X, Y): 291.4858, 500.48877
   .2. (X, Y): 289.98328, 498.9873
   .2. (X, Y): 290.48413, 498.34665
   .2. (X, Y): 290.48413, 499.50812
   .2. (X, Y): 289.15115, 499.4878
   .2. (X, Y): 287.6314, 499.4878
   .2. (X, Y): 286.37064, 499.4878
   ...
2. Android 5.1 (**ASUS Nexus 7**)
   .0. (X, Y): 528.5714, 813.4286
   **stop**. nothing happens here. I do a tiny finger moving:
   .2. (X, Y): 537.51135, 816.00323
   .2. (X, Y): 538.3928, 814.7871
   .2. (X, Y): 538.3928, 813.8571
   .2. (X, Y): 538.866, 813.4286
   .2. (X, Y): 539.7322, 813.4286
   ...

As for me, result on Nexus 7 is better. More logically. Interesting, is it possible to achieve, somehow, similar result on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3? By the way, the same result is on the other Samsung devices: GalaxyTab 4 and smartphone S4. Maybe it's a problem of Samsung devices.. Hm

Comment: Perhaps a touch driver issue, what device are you testing, also what are the X and Y values for each point on ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably just different sensitivity of the touch sensor.  Even when you don't move your finger purposely, you have small movements and pressure changes which will cause differences in capacitance.  Those differences in capacitance will be interpreted differently by different hardware, and some touch screens will think you've made a small move while others won't.  Physical hardware isn't always exact like software.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, the subsequent MOVE calls is your finger "unprecision" to hold stoped.